# Unexpected Row of Data when Joining two tables

Tags: sql-server, query

I want to join both tables, and its giving me a much harder time and it should be, at least it doesn't look that complicated. Would be easier if table b would have a value for ID: 0,  but it doesn't.
So how can I get rid of the double rows in Table D

Table a

```
Article | ID  | Misc |
----------------------
x1      |0    |a     |
x2      |2    |b     |
x3      |1    |c     |
```

Table b

```
Article | ID  | Misc2|
----------------------
x2      | 1   | b-1      |
x2      | 2   | b-2      |
x3      | 1   | c-1      |
x3      | 2   | c-2      |
```

What I want is Table C

```
Article | ID  | Misc | Misc2 |
------------------------------
x1      | 0   | a    |       |
x2      | 1   | b    | b-1   |
x2      | 2   | b    | b-2   |
x3      | 1   | c    | c-1   |
x3      | 2   | c    | c-2   |
```

What I get is Table D

```
Article | ID  | Misc | Misc2 |
------------------------------
x1      | 0   | a    |       | correct
x2      | 0   | b    | b-1   | ID false
x2      | 1   | b    | b-1   | correct
x2      | 0   | b    | b-2   | ID false
x2      | 2   | b    | b-2   | correct
x3      | 0   | c    | c-1   | ID false
x3      | 1   | c    | c-2   | correct
x3      | 0   | c    | c-1   | ID false
x3      | 2   | c    | c-2   | correct
```

My query:

```
Select  
  a.Article,
  a.ID,
  a.Misc,
  b.Misc2
From 
  [table] a
    Inner Join 
        [table] b
    On  
        b.article =  a.article 
        And (
            a.ID = 0 
        OR  a.ID = b.ID
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `LEFT` (outer) join. Try this:

```
SELECT  
  a.Article,
  COALESCE(b.ID, 0) AS ID,
  a.Misc,
  b.Misc2
FROM 
  [table] a
    LEFT JOIN 
        [table] b
    ON
        b.article =  a.article ;
```

You may want to use `COALESCE(b.ID, a.ID)` instead of `COALESCE(b.ID, 0)`, depending on what you want to show (`a.ID` or always `0`) for articles that appear in `a` but not `b`.

Tested in: [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=efd6fb011a1f60dcee679a3b75309741)
(test kindly provided by @McNets)